# Auth service user is null

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I'm setting `route guard` to separate authenticated user from guest. I wrote a `auth-guard service` and an `auth service`. The user data is getting set in the local storage but `console.log()` prints `user` as `null`.

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}
  // ...
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean{
    const user: any = localStorage.getItem('user');
    console.log(user); // null in console
    if (user !== null
      && user.token !== null
      && user.token_deadline !== null
      && new Date(user.token_deadline) > new Date())
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

**auth-guard.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service'


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {

  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {

    return(this.authService.isAuthenticated())
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are setting the user in local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are injecting `Storage` as `storage`, but in your method you are calling `localStorage`. This doesn't seem right. Shouldn't it be `this.storage` ?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {}
  // ...
  public isAuthenticated(): boolean{
    const user: any = this.storage.getItem('user'); // <-- here
    console.log(user); // null in console
    if (user !== null
      && user.token !== null
      && user.token_deadline !== null
      && new Date(user.token_deadline) > new Date())
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```